# How can I save changes to a docker container and export it as a docker image when running custom image build step in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, docker-image, google-cloud-build

I am trying to create a CI pipeline to automate building and testing on Google Cloud Build. I currently have two seperate builds. The first build is triggered manually, it calls the grc.io/cloud-builders/docker builder to use a dockerfile that creates a Ubuntu development environment with the required packages for building our program, I am currently just manually calling this build step because it shouldn't change much. This step creates a docker image that is then stored in our Google Cloud Container Registry. The cloudbuild.yml file for this build step is as follows:

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image_folder', '.']
      timeout: 500s
images: 
- gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image_folder
```

Now that the docker image is stored in the Container Registry, I set up a build trigger to build our program. The framework for our program will be changing so it is essential that our pipeline periodically rebuilds our program before testing can take place. To do this step I am refering to the previous image stored on our Container Registry to run it as a custom builder on google cloud. At the moment, the argument for our custom builder calls a python script that uses python `os.system` to give commands to the system that invokes the steps required to build our program. The cloudbuild.yml file for this build step is stored in our Google Cloud Source Repository so that it can be triggered from pushes to our repo. The cloudbuild.yml file is the following:

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image_folder:latest'
      entrypoint: 'bash'
      args:
        - '-c'
        - 'python3 path/to/instructions/build_instructions.py'
timeout: 2800s
```

The next step is to create another build trigger that will use the build that was built in the previous step to run tests on simulations. The previous step takes upwards of 45 minutes to build and it only needs to be built occasionally so I want to create another build trigger that will simply pull an image that already has our program built so it can run tests without having to build it every time.

The problem I am having is I am not sure how to save and export the image from within a custom builder. Because this is not running the gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker builder, I do not know if it is possible to make changes within the custom builder and export a new image (including the changes made) from within this custom builder without access to the standard docker builder. A possible solution may be just to use the standard docker builder and use the `run` argument to run the container and use `CMD` commands in the dockerfile to execute our build then list another build step to call `docker commit`. But I am guessing that there should be another way around this.

Thanks for your help!

TDLR: I want to run a docker container as a custom builder in Google Cloud Build, make changes to the container, then save the changes and export it as an image to Container Registry so that it can be used to test programs without having to spend 45 minutes building the program every time before testing. How can I do this?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly then solution will be, to create a Dockerfile based on Ubuntu or even alpine image, put all the steps you perform for custom builder like installing dependencies, library, etc. Keep an argument in the dockerfile for other image you want to test, so that image name can be passed as an argument during Docker run. And then build the Docker image and push it to gcr.io. So this will save your custom build time. So whenever required you can pull the image and do all works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, this is what I did:

```
steps:
# This step runs builds the docker container which runs flake8, yapf and unit tests
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'BUILD'
  args: ['build',
         '-t',
         'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog:$COMMIT_SHA',
         '.']
  # Create custom image tag and write to file /workspace/_TAG
- name: 'alpine'
  id: 'SETUP_TAG'
  args: ['sh',
         '-c',
         "echo `echo $BRANCH_NAME |
          sed 's,/,-,g' |
          awk '{print tolower($0)}'`_$(date -u +%Y%m%dT%H%M)_$SHORT_SHA > _TAG; echo $(cat _TAG)"]
  # Tag image with custom tag
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'TAG_IMAGE'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c',
         "docker tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog:$COMMIT_SHA gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog:$(cat _TAG)"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  id: 'PREPARE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT'
  args: ['cp',
         'gs://my_sa_bucket/mysql2dc-credentials.json',
         '.']
- name: 'docker.io/library/python:3.7'
  id: 'PREPARE_ENV'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  env:
  - 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/workspace/mysql2dc-credentials.json'
  - 'MYSQL2DC_DATACATALOG_PROJECT_ID=${_MYSQL2DC_DATACATALOG_PROJECT_ID}'
  args:
  - -c
  - 'pip install google-cloud-datacatalog &&
     system_tests/cleanup.sh'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'SYSTEM_TESTS'
  args: ['run',
         '--rm',
         '--tty',
         '-v',
         '/workspace:/data',
         'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog:$COMMIT_SHA',
         '--datacatalog-project-id=${_MYSQL2DC_DATACATALOG_PROJECT_ID}',
         '--datacatalog-location-id=${_MYSQL2DC_DATACATALOG_LOCATION_ID}',
         '--mysql-host=${_MYSQL2DC_MYSQL_SERVER}',
         '--raw-metadata-csv=${_MYSQL2DC_RAW_METADATA_CSV}']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'TAG_STABLE'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c',
         "docker tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog:$COMMIT_SHA gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog:stable"]
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mysql2datacatalog']
timeout: 15m
```

1. Build docker Image
2. Create a Tag
3. Tag Image
4. Pull Service Account
5. Run
   Tests on the Custom Image
6. Tag the Custom image if success

You could skip 2,3,4. Does this work for you?